# Why is the union of $\mathbb{N}$ equal to $\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

From Goldrei's *Classic Set Theory*:

> Show that $\bigcup \mathbb{N} = \mathbb{N}$.

Something isn't clicking for me. The text defines $\mathbb{N}$ as the intersection of all inductive subsets of any inductive set.

Intuitively, I think this makes sense to me. The elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are part of the sequence $\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \}, \{\emptyset, \{ \emptyset \} \}...$ so that each element of $\mathbb{N}$ is a set. If $\{ x, y, z \}\in\mathbb{N}$ then $x, y, z \in \bigcup \mathbb{N}$, but that will ensure that all the elements of $\mathbb{N}$ are also elements of the union of $\mathbb{N}$, since each successive element of $\mathbb{N}$ contains all previous elements within it.

I'm definitely a novice regarding all of this, so I would appreciate your help with the following:

1. How's my intuitive take? Is this a good way to think about the problem?
2. How might I structure my proof? I'm feeling confused about this.
3. What would be a good follow-up exercise to help me further practice and refine my thinking about these ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove that two sets are equal, you need to prove that one is a subset of the other and vice versa. So handle $\mathbb N\subseteq\bigcup \mathbb N$ and $\bigcup\mathbb N\subseteq \mathbb N$ one by one.

$\mathbb N\subseteq\bigcup \mathbb N$ is straightforward -- since you (hopefully) know that $\mathbb N$ is itself inductive, any element of $\mathbb N$ is itself an element of the *next* natural, so therefore an element of the union.

For $\bigcup\mathbb N\subseteq \mathbb N$, prove *by induction* that every element of $\mathbb N$ is a subset of $\mathbb N$. (If you haven't proved mathematical induction as a theorem yet, this is essentially an exercise in how to use the smallest-inductive-set definition to justify it). Then use the elementary fact that a union of subsets is a subset.